# Fill the area between two lines (not straight)

Tags: algorithm

[image]
I'm asking about the algorithm that allows to fill with the light green the area between the black and dark green areas. The black area is fixed. The green is the trace between the black areas.
The black and dark green lines could be 1 of 4 directions only - north, west, south and east.

I have some ideas about the algorithm (not the algorithm yet) but think it is prone on errors.

So, I have coordinates of the start and finish (finish is exactly when the green touches the black). I have (xstart, ystart) and (xfinish, yfinish) coordinates and both black and dark green lines that connect that coordinates. And my goal is to fill with a light green color the area in between.

If I find my solution and it is pretty short, I will post it here as well. 
Any idea for this algorithm is highly appreciated.
BTW, the are consists of a small rectangles 1x1. So it is OK to colorize the area with a lines of height (or width) or 1.

Once I find the algorithm, I will try to post it here (if that's not someone's algorithm) or give a link.

Thank you.

P.S. My first idea is to pay the attention there are (always?) even number of lines that cross any horizontal or vertical line.

Comment: Algorithms transform input to output. What is your output? Pixels? Simple polygons? Convex polygons?

Comment: Pixels. The polygons are a set or rectangles.

Comment: you have all line points or only start and end? what is your input data?

Comment: "My first idea is to pay the attention there are (always?) even number of lines that cross any horizontal or vertical line." That's one of the definition used for the inside of a polygon (the other pay attention to the orientation, but your example is not handled with it).

Comment: Only start and end. What I can do is to check the color of any small (1x1) square if it is black, white or green.

Comment: try see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would loop the "image" from top to bottom.

For each line, you would loop from left to right, starting "outside". Every time you hit a vertical line crossing the current line you're looking at, you flip the "outside/inside" bit.

Then you colorize all the squares inside.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
const int scale = 20;

void Main()
{
    var polyline = new[]
    {
        new Point(4, 0),
        new Point(4, 5),
        new Point(10, 5),
        new Point(10, 10),
        new Point(6, 10),
        new Point(6, 3),
        new Point(15, 3),
        new Point(15, 8),
        new Point(14, 8),
        new Point(14, 7),
        new Point(16, 7),
        new Point(16, 0),
    };

    int maxY = polyline.Max(point => point.Y);
    int maxX = polyline.Max(point => point.X);

    var bitmap = new Bitmap((maxX + 1) * scale, (maxY + 1) * scale);
    var previousPoint = polyline[0];

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        // TODO: y=0 should be y = minY - 1
        for (int y = 0; y < maxY + 1; y++)
        {
            bool isInside = false;
            var xCoordinatesOfCrossingLines = new HashSet<int>(
                from index in Enumerable.Range(0, polyline.Length)
                let p1 = polyline[index]
                let p2 = polyline[(index + 1) % polyline.Length]
                where p1.X == p2.X
                where (p1.Y <= y && p2.Y > y)       // must cross the y-slice in downwards
                      || (p2.Y <= y && p1.Y > y)    // or upwards direction
                let x = p1.X
                group x by x into xGroup            // if we somehow have 2 (or an even number of) lines overlapping, don't count them
                where xGroup.Count() % 2 != 0       // so we will only except distinct x values that occur 1, 3, 5, etc. times
                select xGroup.Key);

            // TODO: x=0 should be x = minX - 1
            for (int x = 0; x < maxX + 1; x++)
            {
                // Every time we hit a vertical line, we flip the "is inside" bit
                if (xCoordinatesOfCrossingLines.Contains(x))
                    isInside = !isInside;

                // Colorize all the squares inside
                if (isInside)
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(
                        ScalePoint(new Point(x, y), scale),
                        new Size(scale, scale)));
            }
        }
        for (int index = 1; index <= polyline.Length; index++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, ScalePoint(previousPoint, scale), ScalePoint(polyline[index % polyline.Length], scale));
            previousPoint = polyline[index % polyline.Length];
        }
    }
    bitmap.Dump();
}

public Point ScalePoint(Point p, int scale)
{
    return new Point(p.X * scale, p.Y * scale);
}
```

Output:

[image: LINQPad output]

Comment: This is a very direct implementation of the [even/odd winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-odd_rule).

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard flood fill or raster fill algorithm. I would guess it was solved over 30 years ago. You can find it in any standard textbook, or on the web. Here is a link to a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill.

Basically you walk the line filling pixels or raster lines on one side if they're not filled already. After each crossing you switch to the other side. Getting it working is easy. Getting it fast is hard.

If you're using any kind of competent graphics library from Windows GDI through OpenGL to GPU shader code it's already built in.

Some code here as a source of ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

I solved some closely related problems in order to do "perfect" tracing of bitmap graphics. By "perfect" I mean that the trace follows the bitmap boundaries perfectly (rather than the often superior approach of inferring angled lines and curves). Once you have a vector boundary, converting back to pixels is just polygon rendering - actually a simple case since all edges are horizontal or vertical and at boundaries between pixels.

I planned to use related ideas for generating vector graphics from other vector graphics (e.g. generating a fill that precisely fills the inside of a non-zero-width polygon edge) but haven't done that yet, so haven't updated the notes. You might benefit from that approach too, by working with your lines as vector shapes rather than as already-rendered pixels.

I have a long-winded document with some pretty pictures on my 4shared account [here](http://www.4shared.com/office/UCUbiLvrba/Converting_Bitmaps_to_Vector_G.html). I'll try to keep it there.

Quick summary - the core is defining a set of pixel-long between-pixel boundaries so that, as an edge is followed, it's removed from the set that still need to be followed. Then choose a starting point, follow the boundary clockwise until you loop back to the start point, and repeat until you run out of boundaries to follow.

One technicality for me is that I needed to cope with multi-colour images, which turned out to mean that each pixel boundary is followed twice - once in each direction (because there's a filled region on each side). I doubt you need that - your black and green lines are just boundaries for this purpose, so you can pretend they're the same colour.

Another technicality relates to lines that cross, holes and winding rules, and it appears you *do* care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it : -

> 1. Do floodfill from any unfilled point
> 2. If during a flood fill if boundary of the image are encountered then refill all points in the floodfill with arbitrary color.
> 3. else if floodfill is terminated only by black or green lines then color with light green
> 4. change arbitrary color to white